# Ember redirect old routes

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember app where I am renaming a few routes. I am concerned users may have the old routes bookmarked. Where is the best place to handle redirects from the old route to the new one?

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is `replaceWith`:  [replaceWith documentation](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Route/methods/transitionTo?anchor=replaceWith)

you would use it like this:

```js
// app/router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('old-route');
  this.route('new-route');
});
```

```js
// app/routes/old-route.js
export default Route.extend({
  beforeModel() {
    this.replaceWith('new-route');
  }
});
```

Now, if what you wanted to do is KEEP the original route (which it doesn't sound like you want to do but I mention it for completeness) is use [ember-route-alias](https://github.com/nathanhammond/ember-route-alias)

further reading: [Ember guide on redirecting](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/redirection/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the old routes no longer exist. I have re-named the files. But I still want to be able to redirect users if they try to visit the old route.

Comment: @CaseyGov you should create routes with old names and apply this solution. This is most obvious and easy way of solving your problem. You can also try to create a [wildcard route](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard--globbing-routes) and do all work in it's `beforeModel` method (it has Transition as first parameters which I think should contain info about which url user tried to visit)

Comment: @CaseyGov just generate the old routes again.  That's your only option unless you want to alias the routes, which, as I said before, I'm pretty sure you don't want to do.